# three.js flat color using FlatShading and a texture

Tags: three.js, shader

I'm creating a terrain with three.js and texturing with some grass texture I found, and applying FlatShading so it looks low poly, but the shading only modifies that and I'm still seeing the texture applied, I need each face to have a flat color and not the texture, like this picture:

http://i.ytimg.com/vi/9WFBnc_gPMo/maxresdefault.jpg

Unity using PolyWorld asset, from a terrain with a grass texture for example, it applies flat shading and also uses a flat color as texture (predominant color?)

Comment: confused; if you dont want the texture applied, why are you applying it?

Comment: Because I don't want the terrain to look all with the same color, if you look at the image, you can see that the grass has different colors in each face, that's because of the texture, it serves as a way to apply randomness to the color of the faces.

Here's a detailed process for Unity using that asset (PolyWorld), I'm trying to recreate that look but for Three.js:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9WFBnc_gPMo

Comment: you would need to get the texture mipmaps from webgl (after they have been generated) and apply one of those as texture. Or you can blur your original texture before you apply it.

Answer (score 0):

What you seem to want is inefficient, but one way to accomplish it would be to make sure that all three faceVertexUV values for each triangle face are the same: that is for a triangle *ABC* the UV coordinates are all, say (.4,.6),(.4,.6),(.4,.6)

This means that all pixels of the rendered triangle will have that one uniform UV and you'll always get the same texture color across the triangle (some filtering notwithstanding in very extreme foreshortening cases)